# Display value of row with same id in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

I am trying to make a system which automatically prints out orders, and I am facing a problem right now.
I am trying to make a string in a format which the printer is understanding, and right now, i need to gather the data from database before sending. Now my problem is that in some cases the order_id is the same. Here is an example:

```
+----------+----------------------+
| order_id |     product_name     |
+----------+----------------------+
|     1    |   Pizza with cheese  |
+----------+----------------------+
|     1    |    Coca-Cola Zero    |
+----------+----------------------+
|     2    |       Spaghetti      |
+----------+----------------------+
|     3    |        Lasagna       |
+----------+----------------------+
```

So what i am trying to is gather all the "product_name"'s in one string which have the same "order_id", so it display it as:
"Pizza with cheese, Coca-Cola Zero"

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I don't know if I mentioned it above clearly, but I want to make a PHP script that are displaying it. Sorry if I am confusing.

Comment: "Is there any way to do that?" => definitely. I've done it once. You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`. You can concatenate the results manually. There might be some nice functional-style methods in PHP which let you do it in PHP without writing a single loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS product_names FROM orders GROUP BY order_id;
```

Example in PHP:

```
<?php
    $db_server = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'user';
    $db_pass = 'pass';
    $db_name = 'database';

    $con = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass)
        or die('Could not connect to the server!');

    mysql_select_db($db_name)
        or die('Could not select a database.');


    $sql = "SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ', ')";
    $sql .= " AS product_names FROM orders GROUP BY order_id";

    $result = mysql_query($sql)
        or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>orders</h1>
<table>
   <tr><th>orders_id</th><th>product_names</th></tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $row['order_id'],
                                                $row['product_names']);
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: olafs answer covers the group_concat but it's not a good example of group_concat because the value of product name column will be 'Pizza with cheeseCoca-Cola Zero' for order 1. this answer is an example with the use of separator in group_concat methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can select for this

```
select order_id, count(*), group_concat(product_name)
from orders
group by order_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

This gives you all `order_id`s which have multiple entries with the number of entries and the orders concatenated together. If you don't need the number leave out the `count(*)` in the column list.

If you want *all* orders leave out the `having`

```
select order_id, count(*), group_concat(product_name)
from orders
group by order_id
```

And using that from PHP

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
// use the appropriate select
$result = $conn->query('select order_id, group_concat(product_name) '
                       . 'from orders group by order_id');
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // process the result row
}
```

This is of course just a brief outline. You must add the error handling and fill in what you want to do with the result.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for pointing this out, I reflected this in the answer.

Comment: Could i perhaps use this in PHP?

Comment: @IsmailIsmaiil What do you mean? You can of course call `mysqli_query($link, 'select order_id, count(*), group_concat ...')` and loop through the result set.

Comment: Could you give an example? I am not that well to PHP.

Comment: @IsmailIsmaiil I've updated the answer with a PHP skeleton, which you can expand as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should split up your data in two separate table, since there are relate *1:N* where one order can have multiple products.

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   .... any further information about the order,
   PRIMARY_KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `order_product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `order_product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `order` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

that way you get no multiple orderIds for one order

*Getting one order*

```
select * from order where id=1
```

*Getting all products of an order*

```
select op.* from order o inner join order_product op on op.orderId=o.id
```

Comment: I can't split it up, because it is a part of the PrestaShop sql, if i split it up, i need to change the whole CMS

Comment: this was/should be the approach. the design in the question defeats the purpose of `relational` concept.

Comment: @itachi I believe the table is the question is one of the two tables in this answer.